# req.body return empty in app.delete function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, express

I'm trying to pass some json data to an $http Delete call but the req.body being returned is an empty javascript object

Here is my $http delete call, scenario is a json object

```
    //Deletes the item from the database
   $http({ method: 'DELETE', url: 'http://localhost:3000/scenarios/' + scenario._id, data: scenario}).
       success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(data);
            console.log('success');
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

but in my express response to this function here

```
exports.deleteScenario = function (req, res){
 var deletedScenario = req.body;
 console.log(deletedScenario);
...
}
```

returns `{}` in the console. So how could I pass JSON data to a http DELETE call without the body returns an empty object?

Comment: Works for me -- if HTTP request has an entity-body, it shows up in Express.  Are you sure the browser is sending the body? (verify in your browser's developer tools network panel)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is probably too late to ask, but have you specified
**headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}** in your $http request config?

Http header needs to be explicitly specified(when directly using $http, and it is required if you are using angular $resource) other express won't pick up correct parser then lead to an empty request payload.